# Проблема с получением содержимого папки в android

Tags: java, android

При попытки получить содержимое папки в андроид, выдаёт названия только папок (файлов нет).

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PDFView";
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646984/how-to-list-files-in-an-android-directory

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту проблему, проблема оказалась в эмуляторе. На телефоне все отлично выдает.